# Unable to right click in Mac RDP session

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure

I am connecting to a Windows Server 2012 VM (hosted in Azure) via Microsoft RDP 8.0.9 from my Macbook Pro.

I am having trouble right-clicking within the VM using the trackpad. The usual shortcuts like CTRL+click, CTRL+SHIFT+click or double-tapping, don't work. Double tapping to do secondary click is enabled in System Preferences -> Trackpad.

How can I right click when connected to the VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the 2-finger to right click option in Trackpad settings? That's the MS RDC 'accepted' method.

From Technet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473006.aspx

> How do I enable secondary right-click on your Mac?
>
> In order to make use of the right-click inside an open session you have three options:
>   Standard PC two button USB mouse
>
> Apple Magic Mouse: To enable right-click, clickSystem Preferences in the dock, click Mouse, and then enable Secondary click.
>
> Apple Magic Trackpad or MacBook Trackpad: To enable right-click, click System Preferences in the dock, click Mouse, and then enable Secondary click.

Comment: Yes, I did try exactly that, not working. (And I checked that the preferences is set correct)

Comment: ahh, sorry, I can't really add any more except to confirm I could find no other way except use a mouse. I don't have a trackpad to test with but could not get a right click to be recognised by any of the standard methods you already mentioned.  I assume you tested your right click to be working OK in the Mac itself...

Comment: It's April 2016, and this still doesn't work!

Comment: It's 2017, now this answer works :-)

Comment: Weird :) Btw, I'd give the new MS RDC beta a look at, lots of improvements over the current release [though one bug right now it won't remember the Mac window size, fixed in next beta] - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/ Ah, new beta since I last checked, that bug's fixed now.